# CommandText property not initialised

Tags: c#, sql

I seem to be getting this problem only after I've changed my working code to use a dataview as opposed to textboxes to display a single row of data.

I have the following:

```
static SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection
                       (DBConnection.DBConnection.connectionString);        
    SqlDataAdapter holdone = new SqlDataAdapter(getCommand, dbConnection);      

    DataSet holdall = new DataSet();
    DataSet updateall = new DataSet();
    DataTable invoiceTable = new DataTable();

    DataView invoiceView = new DataView();
```

which is used by

```
public void GetOne(/* connectionString, string invref, string tableref*/)
    {

getCommand = "select *redacted* from " + tableref +  
                                      "where *redacted* = " + invref;

        using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection
                               (DBConnection.DBConnection.connectionString))
        {
                dbConnection.Open();

            holdone.Fill(holdall);

            invoiceTable = holdall.Tables[0];

            dbConnection.Close();


        }

        DataRowView rowView = invoiceView.AddNew();

            rowView["*redacted*"] = invoiceTable;

            rowView.EndEdit();
    }
```

The error reports `holdone.fill(holdall)` as the offending line, however I am unsure as to why, as I'm not using `SQLCommand` as a parameter, rather a parameter of `SQLDataAdapter`.

I'm struggling to see where I've gone wrong?

Comment: What error/exception do you get?

Comment: @Jonny ExecuteReader: CommandText property has not been initialized

Comment: Is a `ArgumentException`, a `NullReferenceException`? Something else? Can you paste the exception details into the question?

Comment: @SonerGönül It is a string - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx703tc9(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Jonny Ah. It is an `InvalidOperationException`.

Comment: Check the syntax of SQL command: probably you should use select [redacted] instead of select *redacted*. Also, add a blank space before " where ...", Regards,

Comment: @AlexBell There's a difference between the command text not being initialized and an invalid command syntax. He would not get the error he gets if he assigned just *some*  text to the command.

Comment: @AlexBell Forgive me, I meant to signify that that text had been removed from my post, not that I am actually using `*`. sorry for any confusion.

Comment: It's OK. There are multiple errors in your original code snippet in addition to just syntax errors, as pointed out by @Thorsten Dittmar. To make your code working you should correct all mentioned ones. Regards,

Comment: @AlexBell There's a misunderstanding here - I was trying to point out that your comment didn't help with the problem mentioned :-)

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar - Yeah, there is a bunch of errors in the code, and even more uncertainties. For example, where in the code the values of strings invref and tableref are assigned? They are passed as parameters, which are commented off. And so on... Rgds,

Comment: @AlexBell They are declared earlier in the class, and given values by another method elsewhere in the program. They are, however, superfluous to this particular question's requirements. 

I cannot be expected to post my entire program here, can I? That would be a ridiculous waste of time for both myself and anyone reading this question.

Comment: OK, case closed :-). Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you *do* set the `SqlDataAdapter`'s select command string to the *current* value of `getCommand` in this line:

```
SqlDataAdapter holdone = new SqlDataAdapter(getCommand, dbConnection);
```

However, as strings are not really pointers, changing `getCommand` afterwords will *not change* the select command of the `SqlDataAdapter`.

What you'd need to do is:

```
public void GetOne(/* connectionString, string invref, string tableref*/)
{

    getCommand = "select *redacted* from " + tableref + "where *redacted* = " + invref;
    using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(DBConnection.DBConnection.connectionString))
    {
        dbConnection.Open();

        holdone.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(getCommand, dbConnection);
        holdone.Fill(holdall);

        invoiceTable = holdall.Tables[0];
        //dbConnection.Close(); // This line is unnecessary, as the connection will be closed by `using`
    }

    DataRowView rowView = invoiceView.AddNew();
    rowView["*redacted*"] = invoiceTable;
    rowView.EndEdit();
}
```

Comment: If I use this, can I do away with the existing overloads in the declaration of `holdone`?   

Namely:   `...ldone = new SqlDataAdapter(removethis)` ?

Comment: I really think that you have a wrong understanding of what an `SqlDataAdapter` is for. You would never create an `SqlDataAdapter` that has a `DELETE` command as its select command... Basically, a data adapter is meant to encapsulate the usual SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE routine. You can assign one `SqlCommand` for each of the operations. The SELECT command will be called upon `Fill`, the other ones will be called depending on the row states of the rows in a `DataTable` upon calling the `Update` method. You may ask yourself if using a data adapter is the right solution in your case.

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean to signify that I am using the adapter in that fashion. I merely meant to specify the particular overloads I was referring to. The actual overloads in question were `(getCommand, dbConnection)`.

Comment: Actually there's no point declaring the `SqlDataAdapter` outside your `GetOne` method, anyway, as it should really be stateless. You might as well create it just before `Fill` and destroy it afterwords (use `using`).

Comment: If that is the case, I assume it is bad form to use the same adapter to perform `update()`? This was my original intention behind declaring the adapter at the root of my class.

Comment: It is not bad form - you can of course declare the adapter "globally" and re-use it whenever you want. It's just bad style to change the command text over and over, as it may be pretty confusing to understand which command text is being used when.

Comment: Aha. Then in this particular case I shall leave my declaration at the root of the handler class. You've been a grand help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're passing the `getCommand` to the `SqlDataAdapter` constructor before you've assigned it the actual SQL command. First innitialize the `getCommand` string, and only then construct the `SqlDataAdapter` object.

Comment: I need to keep the command away from anything else, as I may re-use the adapter. Besides, I just tried this with the same result.

Comment: @Wolfish Then you did it wrong. In the `GetOne` method you *do* set `getCommand`, but you're not assigning it to the `CommandText` of the `holdone` SQL adapter. Remember that you do not set a reference to `getCommand`, but set the internal command text to the current value of `getCommand` in the line `SqlDataAdapter holdone = new SqlDataAdapter(getCommand, dbConnection);`. Changing `getCommand` does *not* change the command text for the `SqlDataAdapter`!

Answer (score 0):

Your `CommandText` is passed to the SqlDataAdapter by Value, not by reference, so changing your variable `getCommand` after the adapter has been created will not affect the data adapter. A really simple demonstration is that this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string r = "Test";
    using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(r, new SqlConnection("")))
    {
        r = "Test2";
        Console.WriteLine(adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText);
    }

}
```

Outputs

> Test

Not

> Test2

You'd need to expicitly change your adapter's SelectCommand.CommandText:

```
holdone.SelectCommand.CommandText = getCommand;
```

For what it's worth reusing your objects like this is not helpful, it barely even saves code. .NET uses connection pooling, so using multiple SQL Connections/Adapters does not necessarily mean multiple pipes to the database. You should also use [parameterised queries](http://bobby-tables.com/):

```
string sql = "select *redacted* from " + tableref + " where *redacted* = @InvoiceParam";
using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, DBConnection.DBConnection.connectionString))
{
    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InvoiceParam", invRef);
    adapter.Fill(holdall);
    invoiceTable = holdall.Tables[0];
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the advice on parameterised queries, I'll be looking into this. As for SelectCommand, @ThorstenDittmar's answer above appears to be working.